# finding file being called in php

Tags: php, joomla

Okay so I have a `joomla` site that uses a compponet that is used to create events or booking times.  My problem is I can't find the form file that I am trying to access within my `joomla administrator componets` directory for the `com` of that plugin.  Here is the URL of that form `makeanappointment/create?dtstart=201404250930&cal_id=5`

So my question is is there a script I can run in PHP to find out all those files being called in and their location?

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a PHP function called `get_included_files()` which returns a list of all files that were loaded via `include`, `include_once`, `require` and `require_once`.

It may be a bit primitive for what you are looking for (it doesn't have the caller line numbers etc), but it will at least show you all the files used during a particular execution. Just add a call to that function near the end of the main script.

Since it returns an array you'll probably need to dump the contents (i.e. `print_r(get_included_files())`.

See the `get_included_files()` [manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) on php.net for more usage details.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for a particular source file, I usually expand the extension installation file on my local machine and then use a search utility to find instances of text used on the web page.

Once I can find the correct source file on my local machine, it's usually fairly easy to find the file on the website.